# IBM JAVA_HOME settings in QSELL not working

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

Basically the problem is that in Qsh production system, but does not change to version 1.7

unset JAVA_HOME

export -s JAVA_HOME=/QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk70/32bit

echo $JAVA_HOME

/QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk70/32bit

java -version

java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap3260sr16fp25-20160422_01(SR16 FP25) )
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 OS/400 ppc-32 jvmap3260sr16fp25-20 160422_01 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20160413_299433
JIT - r9_20160328_114196
GC - GA24_Java6_SR16_20160413_1159_B299433)
JCL - 20160421_01

V7R2M0

QMODEL = 41A

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` is **not** used by shell to find the java executable; it is mostly used by some frameworks and applications. Shells normally use `PATH` to search executables (`PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` or similar - just an idea)

Comment: To add to @user85421, you need to update both. $JAVA_HOME for applications that expect it to be set, and then update your $PATH which probably points at the old jre version.

Comment: My PATH is echo $PATH                  
/usr/bin:.:/QOpenSys/usr/bin

Comment: I test the same script in QA environment and it works but no production system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @user85421 mentions the `JAVA_HOME` is not used by QShell to find executables, it is used by java program to find java libraries and files.
To specify the executable search path, you need to set the `PATH` environment variable. I am not a QShell user but if it is POSIX you can try something like this

```
export -s PATH="/QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk70/32bit/bin:${PATH}"
```

Then to verify, run

```
java -version
```

Please notice that the path you have specified in your question is the directory where all the java installation is, but the executables usually are located in a subdirectory `bin` inside the directory you specified, so I added this in my answer. 
Also, consider this change only works in the shell you have opened and is temporal once you close and open a new shell the `PATH` will be restored to its default value.

Don't hesitate in asking for clarifications or give us your feedback. Regards!

Comment: Thank you. Your answer solved my problem.

Very thankful.

In the CLLE apply RMVENVVAR PATH / JAVA_HOME and ADDENVVAR at job level and it worked correctly when calling myfile.jar 1.7

The strange thing is that in QA environment only applied RMVENVVAR and ADDENVVAR to JAVA_HOME and it worked.